# Route [purchase.store] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I followed a tutorial about integrating Billplz with Laravel from :
https://medium.com/@firdaushishamuddin/building-e-commerce-application-with-laravel-5-8-and-billplz-payment-7d8023de8111

End up with error saying ..

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

Route [purchase.store] not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larabill/resources/views/home.blade.php)
```

I kept going back and forth from the beginning of the tutorial to check if I missed anything. How do you define this Route [purchase.store] ?

```
resources/views/home.blade.php

<form id="newbill-form{{$product->id}}" action="{{ route('purchase.store') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{$product->id}}">
                    </form>
```

```
Http/PurchaseController.php

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $params = $request->all();
        $product = Purchase::find($params['product']);
        // from the guide
        $res0 = new BillplzBill;
        $res0->collection_id = $product->payment_link; 
        $res0->description = "New BIll"; 
        $res0->email = Auth::user()->email; 
        $res0->name = Auth::user()->name; 
        $res0->amount = $product->price*100; 
        $res0->callback_url = "yourwebsite@example.com"; 
        // and other optional params
        $res0 = $res0->create_bill();
        list($rhead ,$rbody, $rurl) = explode("\n\r\n", $res0);
        $bplz_result = json_decode($rurl);

        // Store the bill into our purchases
        $purchase = new Purchase;
        $purchase->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $purchase->product_id = $product->id;
        $purchase->bill_id = $bplz_result->id;
        $purchase->save();
        return redirect($bplz_result->url);
    }
```

tried this

```
Route::post('/store', 'PurchaseController@store')->name('purchase.store');
```

and got error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: You have to use route name `})->name('purchase.store');` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Comment: Seems like a different error @ShaifulRizalShaharudin. Can you give us more information? Maybe your new error warrants a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Does `Purchase::find($params['product']);` return something? Because `Purchase::find()` returns either a `Purchase` model or `null`. And then, 3 lines after you're using a property.

```
$product = Purchase::find($params['product']);
$res0 = new BillplzBill;
# If $product is null, then this line will trigger the "Trying to get property of non-object" error
$res0->collection_id = $product->payment_link;
```

Comment: it's returning 1 product from database

Answer (score 0):

You have not check if the product is available or not so you have to write code as

```
$product = Purchase::findOrFail($params['product']);
$res0 = new BillplzBill;
$res0->collection_id = $product->payment_link;
```

Comment: product is available